# Can I store the filenames in a directory in separate variables in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example, I would like to take a directory and I would like to filenames such as much.png and notmuch.png and store them as seperate values, like file1 = much.png and file2 = notmuch.png, but have it work for as many or as little files as there are in the directory. My overall project is to get the names of files and randomize them, like if there are 5 files just swap he names of all of them around. If anyone could help with that as well that would be cool.

Comment: You don't *need* separate variables for each filename.  A single list containing all of the filenames would be vastly more convenient - and is exactly how `os.listdir()` gives you the names, anyway.

Comment: ^ Yup, I have it in a list currently, but I do not know how I am supposed to split it, I do not want to name a file ['much.png', 'notmuch.png'], I want to name it 1 of the 2, that is what I was asking